# I can't connect to my hugo site on docker

Tags: docker, hugo

Recently I created a docker and there I created a `hugo` site, the problem comes when I start the page but doesn't charge in my navigator. I'm new at this so I'm lost.

This is what shows up when I start the site:

```
WARN 2019/12/09 16:15:11 found no layout file for "HTML" for "taxonomyTerm": You should create a template file which matches Hugo Layouts Lookup Rules for this combination.

                   | EN  
+------------------+----+
  Pages            |  4  
  Paginator pages  |  0  
  Non-page files   |  0  
  Static files     | 17  
  Processed images |  0  
  Aliases          |  0  
  Sitemaps         |  1  
  Cleaned          |  0  

Total in 6 ms
Watching for changes in /cvcontainer/cv-online/{archetypes,content,data,layouts,static,themes}
Watching for config changes in /cvcontainer/cv-online/config.toml
Environment: "development"
Serving pages from memory
Running in Fast Render Mode. For full rebuilds on change: hugo server --disableFastRender
Web Server is available at http://localhost:1313/ (bind address 127.0.0.1)
Press Ctrl+C to stop
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. `I created a docker and there I created a hugo site` => How did you do that ? What is the content of your dockerfile ? How did you build your image exactly ? What command did you use to start your container ? Did you map port 1313 (which seems to be used by hugo) to a port on your host ? Which address exactly are you using to display the site in your browser ? What do you see exactly (connection refused, no route to host....)?... Please edit your question and add some more information. In the current situation, it not possible to help you out.

Answer (score 5):

Try adding `--bind 0.0.0.0` when running the server. For ex. `CMD ["hugo", "server", "--bind=0.0.0.0"]`.

Comment: This solved my problem, but what does it do? What is "binding". I want to educate myself.

Comment: Dude.. this was a mircacle.. I spend 2 days figuring out what was going wrong and you made my day.. Thank you on behalf of the human species ;)